# How to change the Font Size and font color in a whole Application dynamically

Tags: fonts

i want to change the Font Size and Font color in  Application  dynamically.please tell me how can  dynamically we change font size and  font color in my application .this is basically web service based application . i want to change my color and font size at run time.

Comment: We cannot tell you if you don't say what type of application, what toolkits, what platform.

Comment: thanks for your response ,dialer base application,4.2 and dynamic change color and font sizi in android

Comment: Those are vital informations for your question. So go, _edit_ the question, add the information and add tags accordingly. How do you expect people to answer you if you don't even care to tell them such things? Think before posting a question!